# MySQL if exists, then return 'id' of the field else insert new line and return last inserted id?

Tags: mysql

What is wrong with this statement?

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM `apples` 
WHERE `apples`.`color` = ? 
AND `apples`.`size` = ?) 
SELECT `apples`.`applesID` 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO `apples` (`color`, `size`) 
VALUES(?,?);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the proper syntax for [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html):

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `apples` 
    WHERE `apples`.`color` = ? 
    AND `apples`.`size` = ?) THEN
    SELECT `apples`.`applesID`;
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `apples` (`color`, `size`) VALUES(?,?);
END IF;
```

Comment: THank you, but I mean, not as a stored function, but as a one-line query.
As a query, this does not work :(